# Wave equation with porous medium term

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation

The classical porous media equation is

$$u_t - \Delta(u^m) = 0 \quad m>1.$$

Has the (degenerate) wave equation
$$u_{tt} - \Delta(u^m) = 0$$
been subject of studies? What would the physical interpretation of such a wave equation be?

Comment: How to interpret the equation for negative $u$? Or should $m$ be a odd integer?

Comment: for $m=2$ and a minus sign in front of the Laplacian this is the zero-water-depth limit of the [Boussinesq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boussinesq_approximation_(water_waves)) shallow-water wave equation

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you. Do you have a reference where such zero-water-depth limit is studied?